# Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

Tags: android, video, mp4, android-videoview

Using video view I have tried to play mp4 videos.

Currently this link works https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4

However when I try these they wont play

1. http://vis-insight.com/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb%20(1).mp4
2. http://vis-insight.com/video/m-1.3.6.1.4.1.5962.99.1.3591259986.1562889010.1377980827474.2.0.mp4

I keep getting the Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side and error (1, -38)

My code is as follows.

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
// Set progressbar title
pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
// Set progressbar message
pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
// Show progressbar
pDialog.show();

try {
    // Start the MediaController
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
            getActivity());
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
    // Get the URL from String VideoURL
    //Uri video = Uri.parse("https://staging.vitalengine.com/dicom-cstore/dicom-media?media=ABEL_3/1.3.6.1.4.1.5962.99.1.3591259986.1562889010.1377980827474.3.0/1.3.6.1.4.1.5962.99.1.3591259986.1562889010.1377980827474.4.0/m-1.3.6.1.4.1.5962.99.1.3591259986.1562889010.1377980827474.2.0.mp4");
    Uri video = Uri.parse("https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4");
    //Uri video = Uri.parse("http://vis-insight.com/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb%20(1).mp4");
    mVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}

mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```